# File available in python2 but not in python 3

Tags: python, request

I'm trying to write this python program. I'm trying to import requests as

```
import requests
```

then in the terminal, I run,

```
python3 filename.py
```

I get an error saying

```
No module named 'requests'
```

However, when I pip install requests, I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

What do I do from here?

Comment: `pip3 install requests` It is even telling you which python version the requirement is satisfied for in your output.

Comment: However, isn't that an inefficient use of memory? How are the requests in the python2.7 directory different from the pip3 installed one?

Comment: @AvishekMondal Python 2 and Python 3 are incompatible.  The Python 2 version of the `requests` module is written for Python 2, and similarly for the Python 3 version.  You will need both if you are using the `requests` module from both 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two version of python running on your system, when you try to run pip it runs the python 2.x version instead of python 3.x version, try to run pip this way

```
    py -3.x -m pip install requests
```

Where x is specific python version installed on your system(eg. 3.4 or 3.5...)

This will install requests for python 3.x version

Answer (score 0):

As chrisz mentioned, I had to do pip3 install requests and it solved the problem